# Explicit calculation of G-CW(V) structure of a G-space

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, cw-complexes, equivariant-homotopy

I know explicitly the $Z/6$-CW($ξ^2$)-complex structure of $D(ξ^2)$, where $ξ$ is the non-trivial irreducible representation of $Z/6$ without fixed points. I am looking for an explicit calculation of the $Z/6$-CW($ξ^2$)-complex structure of $D(2ξ^2)$. It will be great if someone can kindly provide an explicit description of this geometric structure.